# Customising rewrite rules for CPT single post URL to work as paged URL

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, paged

I've got a CPT called `Service` registered as following:

```
$args = array(
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'services', 'with_front' => false),
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array(
      'title'
      'editor',
      'thumbnail',
      'author',
      'revisions'
    )
);
register_post_type('service', $args);
```

I have a page called "Services" that has got a custom template assigned to it that displays all of the services with their permalinks of type `services/copywriting` (where 'copywriting' is the name of the Service). So far so good.

I've got another CPT called `Case Study`. Now, the `Case Studies` are connected to `Services` posts via [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin.

I'm trying to do the following: to use a single `Service` post URL of type `/services/copywriting` to display all `Case Studies` associated with that `Service`.

For that purpose I've added the template redirect rule as following: so that instead of `single.php` template the `archive.php` template will be displayed.

```
add_action("template_redirect", 'template_redirect');
function template_redirect(){
    global $wp, $wp_query;

    // if Service CPT and it's a single page URL then redirect to archive.php template
    if($wp->query_vars["post_type"] == "service" && is_single()){
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/archive.php');
            exit; //thanks to @kaiser's comment
    }
}
```

In the `archive.php` template I've got:

- a custom SQL that gets all the `Case Studies` associated with current `Service` (that I determine by looking at the URL `services/copywriting` where 'copywriting' is the current service).
- a function that creates links for pagination of type `services/copywriting/page/<page_num>`

However, those links of type `services/copywriting/page/<page_num>` don't work and they always get redirected to the single `Service` URL link `services/copywriting`.

Is there something I can add to re-write rules or filters or something to make the paged links work in that manner? So that `services/copywriting/page/2` will work and would be directed to `archive.php` template where my custom SQL will kick in and display the correct `Case Studies`.

Do I have to have a dedicated template rather than `archive.php`?

I would really appreciate any tips and help!

Many thanks,
Dasha

**EDIT**

I've installed [Rewrite Analyzer plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/). And the test for `services/copywriting/page/2` matched the following pattern:

```
services/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$
```

with the following substitution:

```
service: copywriting
paged: 2
```

I've no idea what it means though :(

**EDIT 2**

OK, I've tried adding a rewrite rule as following in the `functions.php`:

```
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite_add_rewrites');
function my_rewrite_add_rewrites(){

    //rewrite rule for Service single post, make it work as paged
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^services/(.+?)/?(page/([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=service&service=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

I've flushed the rewrite rules. However, when I go to URL of type `services/copywriting/page/2` it always just displays the URL without the page bit `services/copywriting/`.

I can't figure out what's wrong. Is my regexp wrong or the `index.php` construction or both?

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: For rewrite rules take a look at this [article](http://pmg.co/a-mostly-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-rewrite-api). For your `template_redirect`: Don't forget to `exit;` afterwards. Else it won't work. And furthermore: Look at [`locate_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template)

Comment: I've tried to add the rewrite rule specified under **EDIT 2** in the main question. Still no luck :( I would really appreciate any further advice! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I got it working more or less correctly, although there is still a **small problem** left, please read on..

Here is what I've got:

in `fucntions.php`:

**Rewrite rules**

```
add_action('init', 'my_rewrite_add_rewrites');
function my_rewrite_add_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^services/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=service&order=ASC&orderby=menu_order',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^services/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$',
        'index.php?post_type=service&paged=$matches[2]&order=ASC&orderby=menu_order',
        'top'
    );
}
```

**Redirect rule**

```
add_action("template_redirect", 'my_template_redirect');
function my_template_redirect(){
    global $wp_query;

    // if Service CPT URL then redirect to archive.php template
    if($wp->query_vars["post_type"] == "service"){
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/archive.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

So now, the URLs of type 'services/copywriting' and 'services/copywriting/page/2' and so on are working.

However, there is a small **problem left**. For example, if I've got 2 pages of copywriting services in total then the following two URLs are working correctly:

- services/copywriting/
- services/copywriting/page/2

However, the URL with a "non existing page" doesn't get redirected to `404` template, but still displays `archive` template with, obviously, empty content. So how can I make sure that such "non existing" paged URLs will be redirected to `404` template correctly? For example, `services/copywriting/page/3` URL when there are only data for 2 pages.

**EDIT**

I have just also noticed that when a non existing service is referenced as in 'services/bla-bla' then the `archive` template is also displayed rather than `404` template.

I would hugely appreciate any tips, before I go totally mad.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the problem, you want to make your CPT paged. 
After you correctly declared CPT in your functions.php, just make sure that a relevant `single-{posttypename}.php` template has `global $page $paged` declared in the head, and contains reference to wp_link_pages() function.

*Exampli gratia:*

`<div class="navigation"><?php
     wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<strong>Pages:</strong> ', 'after' => '&nbsp;', 'next_or_number' => 'number'));
</div>`

Now this CPT supports `<!--nextpage-->` and your URLs will generate accordingly.

Also [this discussion may help](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-with-custom-post-type-listing?replies=45). Remember - you cannot have CPT and Page with the same name.